# What is a : symbol interpreted as?

Tags: probability-theory, notation

If $\omega$ is some event in the sample space $\Omega$, 
How do I interpret this in words? Specifically, what is the ":" symbol say?

$$\{\omega : X(\omega) = 0\} = \{\textrm{tail}\}$$

Comment: Basically it's just a notation for such that

Answer (score 0):

`:` means `such that`. Your set includes all events which the random variable $X$ maps to $0$, i.e. the nullspace of $X$.

Answer (score 0):

It means "such that."

E.g. the set $\{n: n$ is even$\}$ is the set of $n$ such that $n$ is even - that is, the set of even numbers.

The symbol "$\vert$" is frequently used this way as well, but I believe that is somewhat less common.

Comment: The vertical bar is what I saw a lot of in high school. Heck, some texts still use it.

Comment: @SeanRoberson Yeah, I didn't say that it isn't used ("is frequently used this way as well"); I just get the impression that it's used "somewhat less."